# How to mimic skinned java swing with .net means?

Tags: java, .net, swing, user-interface

Question in short:

What is the easiest way to mimic a swing based (skinned, customized) java GUI with `.NET` means?

Question explained:

Our main app has a swing based skinned (and customized) java GUI.
Apart from that we are going to build some smaller GUI equipped tools. Some of them will be `.NET` based windows applications with a windows forms GUI.
Now, to get a uniform user experience the GUIs of these `.NET tools` should be as close to our java based GUI as possible in both appearence and handling.
What is the easiest way to accomplish this?

Comment: I know you mentioned Windows Forms but I think this could be possible with a Windows Presentation Foundation GUI.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the easiest way to accomplish this?

The easiest way to get a uniform Swing / Swing-like user interface is to implement everything in Java and Swing.

I've not heard of a Swing look-alike UI library for .NET.  I guess it is theoretically possible, but it would be a lot of effort: probably orders of magnitude more work than implementing the tools the easy way.

So your practical alternatives are 1) implement the new tools in Java / Swing, 2) reimplement the old tools in .NET, or 3) forget about having a common UI look-and-feel.

---

This is not a joke answer ...

Comment: I have to agree here, trying to skin the UI to Swing is asking for trouble (especially in interactions in tables etc...) The reverse would be doable, Swing does have a "native" look and feel that is fairly accurate.

Answer (score 0):

Try Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) Themes instead WinForms as allow to change the controls Look & Feel. I think is not as easy and pluggable like Swing but could serve as an starting point.